# Visual Studio 2008 tries to convert a web deployment project every time I open the solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web-deployment-project

I am using a **web deployment project in Visual Studio 2008**.

Now, every time I open my ASP.NET web project solution which contains the web deployment, Visual Studio **asks to convert the project** (I guess from VS 2005 to 2008). I do the conversion and save, but if I close an re-open the solution, VS insists on trying to convert the project.

Anybody who knows how to resolve this annoying problem?

Update - configuration:

- Visual Studio 2008 Professional (german)
- ASP.NET 3.5 (VB.NET as language)
- Subversion/VisualSVN
- 1 web project + 4 library projects + 1 web deployment project (new)

Comment: Is the project version controlled with TFS?

Comment: Source control is Subversion - VisualSVN

Comment: I had similar issue but with TFS. If the project wasn't initially checked out with Team Explorer it always kept me asking for conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

- Right click on the Web Deployment Project in the Solution Explorer of Visual Studio 2008.
- Select "Open Project File"
- Change the ToolsVersion value from "3.5" to "4.0"

(XML of the .wdproj file)

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" ...
```

into

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" ...
```

*That's all!*

Comment: Sure, it's the right one and you can do that now (withoung earning rep.pts.).